# Is there a way to get an XML document instead of HTML from an entity dump?

Tags: xml, linqpad

I Love Linqpad.  Is there a way to get an XML document instead of HTML from an entity dump?

I wanted to use LinqPad.Util to create an XML doc instead of an HTML doc on the LinqToSql Changeset.  I have tried many ways to serialize the changeset unsuccessfully.  The Linqpad util CreateXhtmlWriter works great but I would prefer that it be an XML document.  Any ideas on how to do that quickly?

Answer (score 2):

Right now there's nothing in LINQPad to Dump an arbitrary object graph to XML. However, you should be able to do what you describe quite easily with an extension method. Go to **My Extensions** in LINQPad and write a method like this:

```
public static XElement ToXml (this ChangeSet cs)
{
    return new XElement ("ChangeSet",
        new XElement ("Inserts", cs.Inserts.Select (e => EntityToXElement (e))),
        new XElement ("Updates", cs.Updates.Select (e => EntityToXElement (e))),
        new XElement ("Deletes", cs.Deletes.Select (e => EntityToXElement (e))));
}

static XElement EntityToXElement (object o)
{
    return new XElement (
        o.GetType().Name,
        o.GetType().GetFields ().Select (f => new XElement (f.Name, f.GetValue (o))));
}
```

Then, in any query, you can go:

```
GetChangeSet().ToXml().Dump();
```